# Win 10 requires 4 bootups before 2nd (second) display is active (HDMI-attached to NVIDIA GeForce GT 720)

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, bios

My desktop Win 10 computer is about 4 years old. Several years ago I added a 27" Samsung TV, HDMI-attached as a 2nd display to my NVIDIA GeForce GT 720 adapter. It worked fine.

About a month ago I had some computer boot issues that were fixed when I re-flashed my MSI Z97 motherboard bios (I do not think the 2nd display issue started at exactly the same time, but a little later, so I'm not inclined to think it is bios-related).

When I power-on boot the computer, only the main display comes up (with all my desktop icons crammed onto it). If I do a power-off (forced) shutdown, then power the computer up, it again comes up with only the one display (the 2nd display is not activated, Windows does not appear to see it).

But if I repeat the power-down/power-up 3 more times after the initial attempt, on the 4th attempt the 2nd display comes active as soon as the Win 10 welcome screen appears.

It is very consistent, it *always* requires 4 power-button boots to get the second display to work (does not matter when the machine is subsequently shut down, either immediately or after many hours).

I tried removing all user startup programs via mscnfg (except anti-virus, which do not appear in mscnfg). I tried reloading the display adapter bios (it is the most current version); I do not see any settings in the bios that would affect the second display.

Comment: Have you tried playing with the HDMI power choices crap ***on the TV itself***?  That is what >I< would do if I didn't know where to go.  The TV could be every bit as much the cause as the gfx card IMHO.

Comment: Yes, but not a lot of choices other than the signal source (HDMI). The TV has been the second display on this computer for about 4 years, using the same display adapter. I've been mucking around in the computer bios settings but I'm not knowledgeable on bios and I haven't come across anything that pertains to the display(s) as yet (and frankly, didn't expect to, since the display adapter handles displays, not the bios).

Comment: SOLVED! The issue turned out to be an obscure setting in the bios. I had re-flashed the bios several months ago after a problem occurred where I was unable to boot the operating system; apparently the setting changed when I re-flashed the bios at that time but I was fixated on the boot issue and didn't associate it with the subsequent second-display problem. The setting was "Integrated Graphics Devices Configuration > Multi-Monitor"

Comment: NICE!!  Congrats.

Comment: Redux: the problem came back. Upon more searching the internet I found an item that fixed the problem; it turned out to be a Win 10 setting for "fast boot".

Comment: ...disable fast boot through Control Panel\Power Options\Choose what the power buttons do\Change settings that are currently unavailable\untick "Turn on fast startup".

If the symptom disappears, it means that the issue is related with boot sequence.

Comment: COME ON WAYNE!! :)  Post yourself this answer.  Get the points.  Help out the next person who is looking for the same.

Comment: I DID post the answer: it was the Win 10 "Turn on fast startup" setting that caused my boot-up issue. I don't know WHY it causes a problem, or how it was set (I suspect a Windows 10 update set it), but turning fast startup off fixed my problem, allowing both displays to come up when I boot the computer.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/76c108e9-ad45-44fd-a827-2f5f8069226f/2nd-monitor-on-restart-only

Comment: https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/technology/speed-up-windows-10-boot-time-using-fast-startup/ar-BB1efkk1